# Storing documents and backups on several different drives

Tags: filesystems, mount, backup, hard-disk, raid

Currently I have Ubuntu installed on a 120GB SSD.

However I also have 3 more hard drives installed on the computer, 2 x 640GB in aRAID array and a 60GB SSD.

What I am trying to achieve is to use the 640GB drive to store all my documents etc, the 120GB SSD to only Ubuntu and programs and then the final 60GB SSD to back up the most important documents from the 640GB drives. This must be an incremental back up system and not replace the file each time.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please fix your Shift key.

Answer (score 3):

Part I: File system layout

1. Create a Raid1-array out of the 2x640GB (`mdadm`) and format the array with, e.g., `ext4` (You loose all data on those drives!).
2. Format the 60GB SSD with, e.g., `ext4` (You loose all data on this drive!).
3. Adapt `/etc/fstab` on the ubuntu drive: Add two entries for the array and the 60GB SSD. It depends on your flavor to mount the array either as `/home` or as additional folder in `/home/<yourAccount>/documents`.

Part II: Backup

1. Install `rsnapshot` on the ubuntu system.
2. Configure rsnapshot `/etc/rsnapshot.conf` to fit your needs. Particularly, I want to point out to use the parameter `snapshot_root` to point to the mount point of your 60GB SSD, and to insert the files/folders which you want to backup at the end of the file. Note, that you also can simply use folders (like `/etc`) of the ubuntu drive to be backed up.
3. Install cronjob which regularly executes `rsnapshot`.

---

Edit: This answer assumes the non-system drives are either new or you can format the drives which implies a loss of all data on these drives. If these drives contain data are are already formatted as `ext` etc. you don't have to reformat them. However, if they are formatted with `FAT32` or `NTFS`, I would recommend to format the with `ext4`. AFAIK, `rsnapshot`/`rsync` make use of hard links to generate the incremental backup, which is not possible using `FAT` or `NTFS`.